# GDAL module not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run some notebooks that make use of gdal library. I have followed instructions to install it, sometimes the step 5 works well and other does not, 
showing this error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'`

**Step 1**

```
$ apt update
```

**Step 2**

```
$ apt install libgdal-dev -y
```

**Step 3**

```
$ apt install python-gdal -y
```

**Step 4**

```
$ apt install python-numpy python-scipy -y
```

**Step 5**

```
import gdal  # fingers crossed!
```

I  have installed `gdal` library working well on my machine, but I understand, under colaboratory, it install `gdal` on the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried to install gdal through pip? maybe `pip install gdal`?

Comment: Yeah. It generates this error: Failed building wheel for gdal
  Running setup.py clean for gdal
Failed to build gdal: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-u_qz0bl7/gdal/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-1i6tkzli/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-u_qz0bl7/gdal/

Comment: Do `pip install -U setuptools` and `pip install -U wheel` and try again. @jaime-lopez

Comment: Hi @machetazo, I followed your suggestion, and I got this: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-zxxgac1s/gdal/.

Comment: try this `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and `pip install ez_setup` and try again. If it doesn't work, do `easy_install -U setuptools` and try again.

Comment: Hi @machetazo, I got this one after that: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-2gfcbr2z/gdal/. Any other suggestion? I will appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178982/discussion-between-machetazo-and-jaime-lopez).

Comment: I am thinking this error could be related to python version, I mean, I followed the steps for python 2.7, but I have python 3.6. Any suggestion about this?

Comment: See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70275565/how-to-install-gdal-on-google-colab-fast